# Call a method on a specified time interval using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am working on a website where i want to call a method every 30 minutes for example. I want that to be done in background while user is freely using the website. After a lot of research i have found the following function.

```
public static async Task myFunction()
{
    //Stuff Happens on the original UI thread

   await Task.Run(() => //This code runs on a new thread, control is returned to the caller on the UI thread.
   {
        while (?)
        {

        }
        //Do Stuff
   });

//Stuff Happens on the original UI thread after the loop exits.

}
```

I do not know i can change that so it calls a method periodically. Please help with actual code as i am new to C# and asp.net

Edit:
Quartz.net was a better alternative and it worked for me

Comment: Does the user have the web page open that long? How are you triggering `myFunction`?

Comment: i want to trigger it automatically or through a button @RonBeyer

Comment: ASP.NET and IIS make no guarantees that your web-application worker process will be kept alive and will respond to registered timer callbacks. If you have a task that runs periodically you should use your webhost's "cron job" or Scheduled Task feature to invoke a new request to your web-app instead.

Comment: The code you posted is only for desktop applications. There is no "UI thread" in web-applications.

Comment: Can this be modified to work in web applications @Dai

Comment: Have you tried Quartz.net? It is a .net based job scheduler. But do not know if it serves your purpose. But if your need is to run an isolated task which requires no user interaction, give it a try. An asp.net based implementation can be found at https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/254/scheduled-tasks-in-asp-net-with-quartz-net.

Comment: Yeah...Quartz.net is great...give it a try.

Comment: Quartz.net worked perfectly for me @PriyanPerera .